# Reference error can't find variable $compile

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am unit testing an AngularJS directive with Jasmine.

I am getting this error even though I injected `$compile` in a `beforeEach` statement:

`Reference Error: can't find variable: $compile`

```
describe('test', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    describe('testCase', function() {
        var nlElement = angular.element('<div directive></div>');
        var element = $compile(nlElement)($rootScope); // this is where the error is being thrown
        $rootScope.$digest();

        it(...)
    });
});
```

Do I have to include the statements in the second `describe` in the `it` blocks?  Ultimately I want to be able to inject all three of those statements before each test, but I am trying to resolve the `$compile` error at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `describe` blocks are executed before the `beforeEach` statements, which is counter-intuitive to me.  Also, if you want to initialize variables and your directive before your tests (like I did in the second `describe` block, then include it in a `beforeEach` statement, and test your assertions in `it` blocks.

```
describe('test', function() {


    describe('testCase', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function() {    
            var nlElement = angular.element('<div directive></div>');
            var element = $compile(nlElement)($rootScope); // this is where the error is being thrown
            $rootScope.$digest();
        }));

        it(...)
    });
});
```